# Role based user in Angular 8 with enum

Tags: angular, enums, authorization

I'm following this simple tutorial on Angular 8 based on role-based authentitcation. It has this enum:

```
export enum Role {
    User = 'User',
    Admin = 'Admin'
}
```

In the guard, there is a part of the tutorial code that I don't understand (even though it is commented):

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
    if (currentUser) {
        // check if route is restricted by role
        if (route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1)
            The line above what does it mean? There is no user nor admin?
            // role not authorised so redirect to home page
            this.router.navigate(['/']);
            return false;
        }

        // authorised so return true -->And this one, authorizes the normal user? Or the admin?
        return true;
    }
    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
}
```

The thing is, how can the `canActivate` interface distinguish `Admin` from `User`?

Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: [Role.Admin] }
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Aside from this, I know there are other approaches, but this one seems very simple. I wish to confirm if the tutorial recommending the best approach.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(currentUser.role) === -1` checks if the `currentUser` role is in roles array defined in the routes. If it doesn't then route to home page which has the authGuard but doesn't have any roles defined.

And admin route will only be visible to admin user because of the role.